# Why are non-anonymous functions being executed when using click event handler?

Tags: jquery, events, function

I've been exploring the use of custom functions for event handlers.  In this stripped down example, I'm trying to get an alert to pop up when the user clicks a button.

But the alert box pops up immediately as the page loads!  What am I doing wrong?  ( the commented portion does the exact same thing).

If I define the bclick() function like

```
function bclick(foo, bar){ ... }
```

The result is also the same.

JS in the header:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var bclick = function(foo, bar){alert( foo + "  " + bar + "\n");}

//$(document).ready(function(){
//    $("button").click(bclick("Button","Clicked"));
//    });

$("button").click(bclick("Button","Clicked"));

</script>
```

Relevant HTML in the body:

```
<button>Click Me!</button>
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You're evaluating your function before you even pass it.

```
$("button").click(bclick("Button","Clicked"))
```

Here, `bclick` is called with those arguments, and the *result* is being passed to the `click` method. You want to pass it like a normal variable, like this:

```
$("button").click(bclick)
```

The obvious problem with this, though, is the fact that custom arguments aren't passed in. To resolve this, you could pass in an anonymous function that calls your function:

```
$("button").click(() => {
  bclick("Button", "Clicked")
})
```

Comment: You could if you use $("button").click(function(){bclick("Button", "Clicked");});

Comment: This is a trivial example, I know, but this was where I got stuck in something more complicated.  Thanks a lot!

Comment: thank you! you saved my keyboard from going into pieces I cannot believe there is such a big difference between $("button").click(bclick); and $("button").click(bclick());

Comment: thx that helps, you can pass this as well `function() { funcName($(this)); }`

Answer (score 1):

As musicfreak said. However if you want to be really tricky and use the code you have, then youd just need to add `return this` at the end of your bclick function.

Comment: Thanks, I'll mess around with both, I'm sure!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to pass arguments when setting up your event handler, another alternative is to return a function.

```
$("button").click(bclick("Button","Clicked"));

function bclick(foo, bar) { // called once when the event handler is setup
    return function(e) { // called every time the event is triggered
        // you still have the original `foo` and `bar` in scope,
        // and a new `e` (event object) every time the button is clicked
        console.log(foo, bar, e);
    };
}
```